# Why float: CSS property doesn't work in @media queries?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a footer section where if the screen is wider than 815 pixels, some links will be on the rights side, but when the screen is under 815 pixels, I want them to be centred in a new row.

I've tried doing this with @media queries, as well as searching around for a solution, but haven't found a valid one yet.

My CSS code for now is:

```css
footer {
    padding: 25px;
}

footer #right {
    float: right;
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 815px) {
    footer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    footer #right {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<footer>
<h3>&copy; W<strong>3</strong>S &bull; All Rights Reserved <span id="right"><a href="page/support/help_center.htm">Help Center</a> | <a href="page/support/about.htm">About</a> | <a href="page/blog/blog.htm">Blog</a></span></h3>
</footer>
```

I have tried using "width: 100%;", "float: center;", and many more, but nothing worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are vanishingly few reasons to use `float` in 2022, and if you inspect the span in the browser's dev tools you'll see that the `float` rule is applied according to the media query. The problem is that float doesn't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Using `float` is considered a bad practice nowadays. There are better alternatives like `flexbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `float: none`

While I would recommend using `display: flex` as mentioned in [dippas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71577272/5771750), here is how you would do it using `float`s.

```css
footer {
    padding: 25px;
}

footer #right {
    float: right;
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 815px) {
    footer {
        /*  Unnecessary, since footer normally has display: block 
 which is width: 100% by default */
        /* width: 100%; */
        text-align: center;
    }
    footer #right {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<footer>
<h3>&copy; W<strong>3</strong>S &bull; All Rights Reserved <span id="right"><a href="page/support/help_center.htm">Help Center</a> | <a href="page/support/about.htm">About</a> | <a href="page/blog/blog.htm">Blog</a></span></h3>
</footer>
```

Also, using a mobile-first CSS approach to reduce lines of code:

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
}

footer #right {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 815px) {
  
  footer #right {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h3>&copy; W<strong>3</strong>S &bull; All Rights Reserved <span id="right"><a href="page/support/help_center.htm">Help Center</a> | <a href="page/support/about.htm">About</a> | <a href="page/blog/blog.htm">Blog</a></span></h3>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget `float`s,  use `flexbox`, also try using mobile-first approach (`min-width`)

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 816px) {
  footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h3>&copy; W<strong>3</strong>S &bull; All Rights Reserved</h3>

  <span id="right">
    <a href="page/support/help_center.htm">Help Center</a> | 
    <a href="page/support/about.htm">About</a> | 
    <a href="page/blog/blog.htm">Blog</a>
  </span>
</footer>
```